# CSS continues browser attributes

Tags: css, cross-browser, css-animations

Currently there is a common approach to write browser attributes for CSS animation as:

```
@-webkit-keyframes wheel-keyframes {

        100% {
          -ms-transform: rotate(360deg); /* IE 9 */
          -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
          transform: rotate(360deg);
        }
}

@keyframes wheel-keyframes {

        100% {
          -ms-transform: rotate(360deg); /* IE 9 */
          -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
          transform: rotate(360deg);
        }
}   //etc
```

Duplication of code is enormous. Can it be done as?

```
@-webkit-keyframes, @keyframes  wheel-keyframes {
        100% {
          -ms-transform, -webkit-transform, transform: rotate(360deg);
        }
}
```

Is there good resource with testing for a list of CSS attributes, e.g. -webkit-animation-timing-function, animation-timing-function, etc?

Comment: Use some css prepocessor like https://learnboost.github.io/stylus/docs/keyframes.html
Check list of CSS animations https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation

Comment: thank you, but autoprefixer is better feet as solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not possible, even in CSS3, to make such continuous statements and minimize file size.

The best tool for automating this process is [Autoprefixer](https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer).

Answer (score 0):

This is most easily done by either a css preprocessor or some gulp or grunt task.
If these terms are new for you, I would recommend to look up [Google Web Starter Kit](https://developers.google.com/web/starter-kit/),
it is very easy to set up and it comes with both a css preprocessor (SASS), prefixer
and other useful things.